# Is it true that an element of a group whose order divides the order a subgroup is an element of the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that the order of $G$ is finite and that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Is it true that an element of $G$ whose order divides the order of $H$ is in $H$?

Here is my attempt:

Let $|G|=n$ and $|H|=m$. Then $m|n$. Moreover, the order of every subgroup of $G$ divides the order of $G$ and if $g \in G$, then$|g|=|\langle g \rangle|$. Since in itself $H$ is a group (under the same operation in $G$), then the order of its element divides $|H|=m$. Thus, if $|g||m$ then $\langle g\rangle\leq H$ which means that $g \in H$.

Can you help me out with this one? I just can find a way put $g$ in $H$.

Comment: Oh, the claim is *so* false...

Comment: Why the downvote? OP tried and failed, so +1 from me for trying!

Comment: Anyway, many thanks for  your insights. I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the assumption that $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: @user1729 I did not downvote myself, but asking for help with proving something that is not true definitely deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: Hmm, don't agree with that, +1 for not being able to prove a false statement! Surprising how many students would be able to prove this when asked to do so.

Comment: @Derek Okay, I understand and agree. I misread the question as "Is it true that..." rather than "prove that...".

Comment: Smart edit Traveler ;)

Comment: @DerekHolt I disagree with the downvote too.

Comment: @Traveler The answers provided address your question. Now think about this: suppose that some finite group $G$ does satisfy your property. What can you say about $G$?

Comment: @the_fox $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: @Traveler Ok, prove it. Add your proof as an answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt A can't disgree more. You never made a conjecture which turned out to be false despite you were very confident at first? These people are about to learn math and a wrong assumption does not make a bad question, but an opportunity for the answerers.

Comment: @M.Winter I think you are missing the point. If you make a conjecture, then you should make it clear that it is a conjecture, and ask for help in deciding whether it is correct or not. If you ask for help in proving something, then it suggests that you are asking for help in solving a problem that you have been given, and it implies that you are confident that the statement is correct. I have on more than one occasion wasted a lot of time trying to help somebody prove something that turned out to be false.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am sorry for the mistake that I have done right here. I cannot assure though that this will the last. Anyway, I appreciate for the time you've given. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 17):

This is not true, let $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \left\{0\right\}$ and $z= (\bar{0},\bar{1})$. The order of $z$ is 2 and the order of $H$ is 2, but $z\notin H$.

**EDIT:** To answer your comments: One can show that any group of order $175$ is abelian. Moreover, $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_7\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{25}$ or $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{7}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_5\oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$ or $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{175}$. Assuming that $|H|=25$ and $|g|=5$ is still not enough to conclude that $g\in H$. Indeed, if $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{7}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_5\oplus \mathbb{Z}_5$ this can still fail!

Answer (score 14):

This is NOT true: $H=\langle (12)\rangle$ as subgroup of $S_3$. Take the element to be $(2 3)$. This has order $2$ and $|H|=2$, but $(2 3) \notin H$.

**Remark** Inspired by the post: for a finite group $G$ we define  a non-trivial subgroup $H$, an *attractor* of $G$, having the property that for any $g \in G$ with o$(g) \mid |H|$, $g \in H$. It is easy to see that such an $H$ must be *characteristic* (that is $\alpha[H]=H$ for every $\alpha \in Aut(G)$), and if $K$ is a subgroup with $H \cap K \neq 1$, then $H \cap K$ is an attractor of $K$. It would be interesting for example for $p$-groups to determine the structure of these attractors. Also, if $G$ has a *normal* Sylow-subgroup, then this is an attractor.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. The formulation is nearly identical, not surprising I guess :)

Comment: Yes funny, you get a +1 from me!

Comment: You get a +1 for not using direct sums! Well, not explicitly, basically you use the Klein four-group as well which immediately is the smallest counterexample.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I don't see a Klein four-group in this answer; $S_3$ has no subgroup of order 4.

Comment: @Andreas Blass, yes that is right but he meant elements of order $2$

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Maybe I was thinking about $V_4$ in $S_4$... But yes, you need at least a subgroup and one element outside this subgroup for a counter example. So a group of order 4 is the smallest possible counter example. That's what I meant.